# Using fs.statSync() and fs.readdir() to get a directory listing

Tags: node.js, fs

I thought I'd share this simple tip for anyone else who has struggled with this while creating a custom http server.

I was trying to use `fs.stat()` to parse the results of `fs.readdir()`, identify directories and files, and separate the two into sorted arrays for display.

Unfortunately, because `fs.stat()` is asynchronous, sometimes it would reach `res.end()` before the arrays were finished populating and written out in `res.write()`, and the program would error out.

So I tried using `fs.statSync` as a drop-in replacement, with the idea that it would force all other processing to wait until it was finished:

```
...
var filesSorted = [];
var dirsSorted = [];

//The "files" variable comes from fs.readdir(), and "url" is
//the path to the directory.
files.forEach(function(file) {
    var fileObj = url + file;
    fs.statSync(fileObj, function(err, stats) {
        if(stats.isDirectory) {
            dirsSorted.push({
                "dirname" : file,
                "creation" : stats['birthtime']
            });
        } else {
            filesSorted.push({
                "filename" : file,
                "size" : stats['size'],
                "creation" : stats['birthtime']
            });
        }
    });
});
...
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. You can't just drop `fs.statSync()` in that way. I **think** (but am not certain) that it's because it runs inside other asynchronous commands that continue without it. It consistently reaches `res.end()` before `fs.statSync()` is even finished pushing values to the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with it for a little while, I decided to try a different approach. Instead of trying to push to `var filesSorted` and `var dirsSorted` from inside `fs.statSync()`, it occurred to me that if I assigned the output from `fs.statSync()` to a variable inside its parent function, the parent function wouldn't be able to complete until `fs.statSync()` was done:

```
var filesSorted = [];
var dirsSorted = [];

files.forEach(function(file) {
    var fileObj = url + file;
    stats = fs.lstatSync(fileObj);
    if(stats.isDirectory()) {
        dirsSorted.push({
            "dirname" : file,
            "creation" : stats['birthtime']
        });
    } else {
        filesSorted.push({
            "filename" : file,
            "size" : stats['size'],
            "creation" : stats['birthtime']
        });
    }
});
```

That worked! And it seems to be effective for other situations where a synchronous call needs to be made inside an otherwise asynchronous function.

I hope other people find this helpful.